# How to interleave two given vectors in APL

Tags: vector, apl, dyalog, interleave

I'm trying to solve a problem using APL, for which I have two vectors `v1` and `v2`, with relative length of at most `+1`, depending on the input. That means that `((≢v1)-(≢v2))∊¯1 0 1`.

What would be the best way to interleave said vectors, so to create a third vector `v3` such that `v3=v1[0],v2[0],v1[1],v2[1],...`?

(If it's relevant, I'm using Dyalog APL version 16.0)

Comment: I guess you could make this question a bit more general, by removing the relative length part, given all answers so far don't consider it (and support any difference) or apply only for equal length

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should work in just about every APL.

```
(v0,v1)[⍋(⍳⍴v0),⍳⍴v1]
```

If you want to worry about either v0 or v1 being scalars, then

```
(v0,v1)[⍋(⍳⍴,v0),⍳⍴,v1]
```

Comment: This is about as classic as it gets.  Very useful idiom.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't mind getting a prototype fill element when the vectors have unequal length, then

```
Interleave←{,⍉↑⍵}
```

will do. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///3zOvJLUoJzWxLPVR24RqnUe9nY/aJj7q3VqLLKWgYaxgqGCiqaBhpGAOZFloAgA)

Otherwise, you can interleave the matching parts, and then append the missing element(s — it works for length-differences greater than one too):

```
Interleave←{
    lengths←⌊/≢¨⍵
    main←,⍉↑lengths↑¨⍵
    tail←⊃,/lengths↓¨⍵
    main,tail
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///3zOvJLUoJzWxLPVR24RqLgUQyEnNSy/JKAYKPOrp0n/UuejQike9WyFyuYmZeUAJnUe9nY/aJsJVTkRSUpKYmQPS29Wsow9XMBnNDB2QKi6FWmQXKGgYKxgqmGgqaBgpmANZFpoA)

Answer (score 6):

Using a Dyalog `dfn`:

```
zip ← {
    mix ← ,⍉↑ ⍺ ⍵
    mask ← ,⍉↑ 1⊣¨¨ ⍺ ⍵
    mask / mix
}
```

The idea here is to mix both arguments, then transpose the result and finally flatten it (`mix`).

Then, we apply the same on an array of `1`s, corresponding to the length of the given arrays (`mask`), and use it as a mask, to filter the prototypes added by the mix primitive.

Note that this allows also for zipping arrays with a difference of length greater than one element.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///vyqzQOFR2wSFai4FIMjNrADzdB71dj5qm6jwqHcXEG@FyCUWZ6NIGj7qWnxoxaEVmKr0QQZx1f7/b6hgrGCqALLDSMFEwYwLwjfHEIHzFczBIjC@KVhEPSO1Uh0spl6SkVqUqs6l7pGak5MPFQvPL8pJUQcA)

Answer (score 5):

As I do not know Dyalog APL, I answer in the old ISO APL from the 1970's years:
`(v1,v2)[⍋((0.5×(⍴v1)<⍴v2)+⍳⍴v1),((0.5×(⍴v2)<⍴v1)+⍳⍴v2]`

The first element will be the one of the longuest vector, if they have the same length, the first element is the first element of v1.

Comment: For how to type APL symbols, have a look [here](https://www.dyalog.com/apl-font-keyboard.htm) and [here](https://abrudz.github.io/lb/apl) and [here](https://github.com/abrudz/Kbd).

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I would solve the original question in APL2:

```
LEN←∊⌊/⍴¨V1 V2 
V3←∊((LEN↑V1),¨LEN↑V2),LEN↓¨V1 V2
```

Answer (score -1):

With vectors of same length use the inner product:

```
 1 2 3,.,40 50 60

┌──────────────┐
│1 40 2 50 3 60│
└──────────────┘
```

Building on top of that begets this dfn :

```
{r←(⍴⍺)⌊⍴⍵⋄(∊(r⍴⍺),.,r⍴⍵),(r↓⍺),r↓⍵}
```

alternatively, we can laminate (keeping the same overall logic):

```
{r←(⍴⍺)⌊⍴⍵⋄(,(r⍴⍺),⍪r⍴⍵),(r↓⍺),r↓⍵}
```